# HTML5 Canvas Object

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

I  have a canvas html element inside an html page as :

```
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="290" height="250" style="background-color:red"></canvas>
```

I want to access the canvas using jquery. If i am trying to access using jQuery its not working, if I try using document.getElementById then only its working.

Here is the code :

```
 var canvas = $("#myCanvas2");
 console.log("Canvas : " + canvas + ", typeof : " + typeof(canvas));
 canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
 console.log("Canvas 2 : " + canvas + ", typeof : " + typeof(canvas));
```

Shouldn't the $("#myCanvas2"); and document.getElementById('myCanvas2'); be same ??

I am getting the following in the console :

```
  Canvas : [object Object], typeof : object
  Canvas 2 : [object HTMLCanvasElement], typeof : object
```

Can the canvas html element be accessed using jquery ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, use the **element** out of the jQuery **object** like `var canvas = $("#myCanvas2")[0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery always wrap his method around the DOM nodes. This is not only the case for canvas.

If you want to access the DOM node Canvas via jQuery, you'll have to use the [`.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$("canvas").get(0).getContext("2d");
// or short hand
$("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
```

*Note you have to pass an `index` to get so you get the DOM node. Otherwise you'll have an array of DOM nodes.*